# what does this mean in Haskell homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]

Tags: haskell

im learning Haskell but I'm having a hard time trying to break down the meaning of

```
homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

do we take a tuple and list?
im confused please help me out thanks

so  the homerge  merges two sorted lists into a sorted list.
but I don't understand the

```
homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

"Implement the higher order insertion sort algorithm hoMergeSort which is similar to merge sort except that an element x is placed before an element y if `fun x < fun y where fun :: a -> b` is a function taken as input by higher order merge sort. In other words, the result of evaluating hoMergeSort fun xs should be a list [y1,y2,..., yn]"
this is the whole question just to provide context

Comment: That's just the type signature of a function. If you provide more context and explain exactly which part you don't understand, you might get some helpful answers, but as it is we don't really know what the question is.

Comment: its supposed to merge 2 sorted list into a sorted list

Comment: @Micheal litchard so sad to hear you downvoted me.

Comment: I'm not downvoting you. I'm downvoting a bad question. This site is about good questions with good answers. It's not about you.

Answer (score 4):

`homerge` takes 3 arguments: a function of type `a -> b` and two lists of type `[a]`. The return value is another list of type `[a]`.

The `Ord` constraint means that the return type of the first argument must be a type with an `Ord` instance, so that the values can be compared with `<`, `>`, etc.

An `Ord` constraint is *not* required for `a`, so this function lets you merge lists of values that aren't otherwise immediately comparable, for example complex  numbers. Two complex numbers `a + bi` and `c + di` aren't directly comparable, but you *can* order them by their real parts (checking `a < c`) or their imaginary parts (checking `b < d`).

```
homerge realPart [2 :+ 5] [3 :+ 4]  -- [2 :+ 5, 3 :+ 4]
homerge imagPart [2 :+ 5] [3 :+ 4]  -- [3 :+ 4, 2 :+ 5]
```